# Regexp: back-reference an optional grouping

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using regular expressions, with this code:

```rb
Regexp.new("^(?<ast>\\\*\\\*)?(?<key>#{@meta_types.join("|")}):(?<value>.*)\\k<ast>?$", Regexp::MULTILINE)
```

What I'm going for is parsing basic metadata like so:

Title: Some title of a book or something

Except, some of the lines have ** around them, and others don't. The problem is that some of the items under `<value>` span multiple lines, so I can't do `?<value>.*?`. Essentially, I need to require the second `<ast>` grouping if and only if there is a first `<ast>` grouping present.

Is there a way to do this, or does someone have a better solution?

*(It's a Word-to-Markdown conversion, and some of the lines were bolded.)

Edit: the solution

```rb
r = Regexp.new("(?<ast>(?:\\\*\\\*)?)(?<key>Title):(?<value>[^\*]*)\k<ast>", Regexp::MULTILINE)
s = "**Title: Some pieces of text with a random\nnewline thrown in for good measure**\n"
r.match s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
(?<ast>\\\*\\\*)?
```

With:

```
(?<ast>(?:\\\*\\\*)?)
```

And remove the final "?" at the end.

This will force the first capture group to exist, even if it matches nothing.

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to work for me...posting results in an edit. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Accepted the answer because it actually WAS the solution to my question. Just had to fix a stupid mistake (forgetting to escape \ inside of double-quotes)